# Can't upload a recorded video longer than a few seconds using React Native & Laravel

Tags: laravel, react-native, video, file-upload

I have a simple React Native app, that makes use of the Camera. I have a button that records video. As soon as the recording is stopped, the video gets sent to an API endpoint that effectively uploads the video to the web.

Everything works great – unless the video is longer than about 5 or 6 seconds.

Anything that is about 7 seconds longer seems to return an error from the web application.

I "have" to assume this is an issue with file size – but, I checked the PHP settings, and they are as follows...

```
post_max_size = 2500M
upload_max_filesize = 2000M
memory_limit = 1000M
max_execution_time = 360
max_input_time = 3000
max_input_vars = 3000
```

There's no way these videos are so big that they would exceed those limits – so I am at a bit of a loss here.

Any idea what I might be missing?

Comment: what error returned from the server ?

Comment: It's hard to say. The error that I am getting in my Expo console just says: "Error: SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<'"

This is because my server is returning some kind of error page, rather than JSON.

But, I can't actually see the error that the web application is returning... and I can't seem to fake it in PostMan, because the file upload is required.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody who might have a similar issue – it turns out that my NGINX settings had an upload limit of their own.

I changed the NGINX settings, and it fixed everything.